# Alignment with minipage in beamer

Tags: beamer, minipage

I want to place two formulas on the same slide, one on the right and one on the left. But it doesn't work. Can somebody help?
This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{NM - Negative-Multinomial}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Generalization of the Negative Binomial when multiple outcomes are considered.
\end{itemize}
\begin{align}
P(\bm{Y}=\bm{y}) = \binom{\beta+m-1}{m}\binom{m}{\bm{y}}\prod_{j=1}^p \pi_j^{y_j}\pi_{p+1}^{\beta}, \label{eq: NM}
\end{align}
Parameters are $(\bm{\pi}, \beta)=(\pi_1, \dots, \pi_{p+1}, \beta)$, $\sum_{j=1}^{p+1}\pi_j=1$, $\beta>0$, $m$ is the size and $\pi_{p+1}=1-\sum_{j=1}^p \pi_j$ is the probability of a failure.
\noindent{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.38\linewidth}
\leavevmode
    \vskip 0pt
    \vskip -\baselineskip
\begin{equation}
    E[\textbf{Y}] = \beta\frac{\bm{\pi}}{\pi_{p+1}} \nonumber
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}}
\hfill{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.38\linewidth}
\leavevmode
    \vskip 0pt
    \vskip -\baselineskip
\begin{equation}
    Var[\textbf{Y}] = \frac{\beta}{\pi_{p+1}^2}\bm{\pi}\bm{\pi}'+\frac{\beta}{\pi_{p+1}}diag(\bm \pi) \nonumber
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Fitted via ML by an iteratively reweighted Poisson regression.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: `\noindent{` forces a space to the left of the first minipage, is that intended?  `\leavevmode
    \vskip 0pt
    \vskip -\baselineskip` is very weird (and not latex syntax) what is the intention of this? I suspect you simply want `{minipage}[t]` but I am not sure.

Comment: Off-topic: `\noindent` does not take an argument. As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out, `\noindent{ ` is almost surely a mistake, as it inserts whitespace to the left of the first `minipage` environment. The twofold occurrence of `\leavevmode \vskip 0pt \vskip -\baselineskip` appears to serve no useful purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case at hand, there's no need to set up `minipage` environments to place the equations side by side. Instead, just insert a `\qquad` spacer between them.

I would also use a single `itemize` environment, and I'd replace `align` with `equation` since ther's nothing to align across rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% define a few math operators:
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}

\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{NM -- Negative Multinomial}

\begin{itemize}
\item Generalization of the Negative Binomial when multiple outcomes are considered.

\begin{equation}\label{eq: NM}
P(\bm{Y}=\bm{y}) = \binom{\beta+m-1}{m}\binom{m}{\bm{y}}
\prod_{j=1}^p \pi_j^{y_j}\pi_{p+1}^{\beta}\,.
\end{equation}

Parameters are $(\bm{\pi}, \beta)=(\pi_1, \dots, \pi_{p+1}, \beta)$, $\sum_{j=1}^{p+1}\pi_j=1$, $\beta>0$, $m$~is the size, and $\pi_{p+1}=1-\sum_{j=1}^p \pi_j$ is the probability of failure.
\begin{equation*}
    \E[\textbf{Y}] = \beta\frac{\bm{\pi}}{\pi_{p+1}} 
    \qquad
    \Var[\textbf{Y}] = 
     \frac{\beta}{\pi_{p+1}^2}\bm{\pi}\bm{\pi}'
    +\frac{\beta}{\pi_{p+1}}\diag(\bm \pi)
\end{equation*}


\item Fitted via ML by an iteratively reweighted Poisson regression.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For reasons not known to me, the OP used `\bm{Y}` in the upper equation but `\textbf{Y}` in the lower equations. I've kept this dichotomy in the code posted above. However, if this were my work, I'd strive to use one or the other notational convention, but not mix and mis-match them.'